# Why were most of the pilots dubbed in A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

When *A New Hope* was made in 1977, many British actors, such as Denis Lawson, portrayed x-wing pilots and others in the film. However, they seem to have all been dubbed by American actors. Did George Lucas or anyone else working on the original film give a reason for doing this?

Comment: it was common in the OT to use British actors/voices for imperials and American accents for rebels simply for the 'refined' aspect, I believe it's actually a tvtrope, evil brit: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilBrit
also look at: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/is-it-true-that-most-imperial-officers-have-british-accents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true that most imperial officers have British accents?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112449/is-it-true-that-most-imperial-officers-have-british-accents)

Comment: What proof do you have they were dubbed, rather than the actor adopting the accent themselves?

Comment: I'm with @Skooba. Given the ADR technology at the time, I'd think any looped dialog would be more obvious. It seems like at least the Gold and Red squadron members who get the most screen time don't seem to be dubbed. Also the production audio would have been made on a sound stage so there wouldn't be many likely technical reasons to loop it.

Comment: Wedge was Dubbed, they have proof of that

Comment: Tiree was also dubbed, there is proof of that as well.